# Flutter on Arch

Tags: linux, flutter, installation

I tried to install Flutter through snap on Arch and everything is fine until this:
❯ sudo snap install flutter --classic

error: cannot perform the following tasks:

- Mount snap "snapd" (10492) ([start snap-snapd-10492.mount] failed with exit status 1: Job failed. See "journalctl -xe" for details.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Uninstall it and follow [this guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux).

Comment: I've also tried this way but when I try to export in PATH works fine (my "echo $PATH" output is this: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/Coding/flutter/bin)
But when I try which flutter only tell me "flutter not found".

Comment: Find manually `flutter/bin`, then run this command `pwd`, and tell us what it displays. Moreover, when you do any changes to `.bashrc` (or `.zshrc`) file, you must restart your terminal: (1) close and open your terminal, or (2) run `source ~/.bashrc`, then try again running `flutter --version`

Comment: Yeah, I'm such an idiot, in the path I originally wrote /home/Coding/flutter/bin but instead the full path is /home/lorenzo/Coding/flutter/bin.
I'm sorry to have done such a dumb error but thank you very much anyway